# Mobile phone app event timing synchronization

Tags: real-time, synchronization, timing, smartphone

I'm trying to coordinate a triggered event across many smartphones within as small a time-frame as possible (ideally have them start within half a second or less of each other).

The problem:
From my experience, the local time value on the devices cant be relied on, and additionally latency can contribute to issues with syncing a value for the current time (imagine trying to get the updated time from some remote source and eventually approaching a decently close idea of the current time locally based on that remote source, ideally within a fraction of a second of said source).

Are there any established techniques, mechanisms, or more accurate sources of some time value reference point that would allow for a planned event to be triggered on multiple devices within a fraction of a second of one another? The more I search, the more I realize this is not a trivial issue, however I thought it would be worth it to query the great minds of stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 3):

I've developed a technology that achieves synchronization of smartphones down to 10 milliseconds. Each devices takes the UTC time from many clocks and makes a non-trivial convolution.
I have applied this to a massive event (http://massivesymphony.org) and I'm now providing the technology for several corporate events.

In case you are interested in more details, my contact is
José I. Latorre
Dept. of Physics, U. Barcelona
j.i.latorre@gmail.com